# Writing into text file

Tags: python, file-io, typeerror

```
f = open("outputdata.txt", 'w')
    for i in range(len(mydose)):
        t = (mygrid[i]+mygrid[i+1])/2.0
        f.write("%12.6f %12g %12g" % (t, mydose[i], myerrs[i]*mydose[i]))
```

The previous code gives me *outputdata.txt* file with all data in a single line. Now, I want to write in 3 columns which are *t*, *mydose[i]* and *myerrs[i]*mydose[i]*. I tried:

```
f = open("outputdata.txt", 'w')
    for i in range(len(mydose)):
        t = (mygrid[i]+mygrid[i+1])/2.0
        f.write("%12.6f %12g %12g" % (t, mydose[i], myerrs[i]*mydose[i],'\n'))
```

which gave me *Typeerror: not all arguments converted during string formatting*.

Could somebody please help me fixing this problem?

Comment: Put the programming language in the tags. Python?

Comment: Why do you have '\n' in the parameters on the f.write

Answer (score 2):

Just add the \n at the end

```
f.write("%12.6f %12g %12g\n" % (t, mydose[i], myerrs[i]*mydose[i]))
```

Answer (score 1):

This should fix your problem:

```
with open("outputdata.txt", 'w') as f:
    for (i, (err, dose)) in enumerate(zip(myerrs, mydose)):
        t = (mygrid[i] + mygrid[i + 1]) / 2.
        f.write("%12.6f %12g %12g\n" % (t, dose, err * dose))
```

In future you might consider using `csv` module (with space separator) to write this file.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot "%s":

```
f.write("%12.6f %12g %12g %s" % (t, mydose[i], myerrs[i]*mydose[i],'\n'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Ues the code as blow:

```
f = open("outputdata.txt", 'w')
for i in range(len(mydose)):
    t = (mygrid[i]+mygrid[i+1])/2.0
    f.write("%12.6f %12g %12g\n" % (t, mydose[i], myerrs[i]*mydose[i]))
```